# How to specify include directory of mpicxx in the command line option of make?

Tags: cuda, command-line-arguments, gnu-make, include-path, mpic++

I am trying to build all CUDA samples by running `make` in the sample's base folder. One of the samples require `mpi.h`, but the system did not have it, which causes an error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '$HOME/cuda_samples/samples/0_Simple/simpleMPI'
/bin/mpicxx -I../../common/inc  -o simpleMPI_mpi.o -c simpleMPI.cpp
simpleMPI.cpp:25:10: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
   25 | #include <mpi.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:371: simpleMPI_mpi.o] Error 1
```

Since I don't have root privilege, I downloaded a deb file for `libopenmpi-dev` package (using `apt-get download` command) and extracted it to somewhere in my user space (using `dpkg -x` command). However, as we can see, `mpicxx` tries to find `mpi.h` in `../../common/inc`, which is not where I installed `libopenmpi-dev` in my user space (I did not notice that untill I installed the package. My bad). So I need to somehow tell `mpicxx` to find `mpi.h` in another directory. I know there is a `-I` option to tell `make` where additional include directories are, but this option does not apply to `mpicxx`. How to pass directory information from `make`'s command line to `mpicxx` is beyond my knowledge. Can you please teach me what option I should use in `make`'s command line to specify include directory used by `mpicxx`? Of course I can manually copy the installed `libopenmpi-dev` package to `../../common/inc` to accommodate original settings in CUDA sample, but I would like to do something cool and learn something new, so I ask here. Thank you in advance for teaching me.

Environment:

- Remote Linux with core version 5.8.0. I am not a super user.
- CUDA version: 11.2
- CPU: Intel Core i9-10900K
- gcc version: (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0
- make version: GNU Make 4.3, Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
- MPI version: 4.0.3

Comment: First understand the difference between make and your compiler.  It's not make that compiles your code and needs to include header files and shows the error message above.  It's your compiler that does that.  So you don't want to add a `-I` option to the make command line, you need to add a `-I` option to the compiler's command line.  make _runs_ the compiler so make controls what options the compiler is started with.  Presumably there's some variable in your makefile that lists compiler options but we can't know what that is.  Often it's a `CXXFLAGS` variable for C++ but it doesn't have to be

Comment: The usual things that need to get updated so that MPI can be used are your `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables.  It shouldn't be necessary to specify them on the `make` command line but that is certainly one way to do it.  Something like this: `PATH=/path/to/mpi/bin:$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/mpi/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH make ...`  With that, `mpicxx` should already know how to find its associated `mpi.h` without you having to specifically identify a path for the compilation command, assuming you either built your MPI from scratch, or installed the `-dev` or `-devel` version of MPI packages

Comment: @Robert Crovella: Yes, there are methods that you may think better, and perhaps I would also agree that's really a better method, but I was asking how to set variables like `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in make's command line. You may think that's foolish but that's what I was asking. In addition, are you sure you really understand the question and the situation? If you think I missed some important information in the question, I'm glad to add it. But please don't think anyone else has to behave exactly the same way as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The include directory in Makefile is held in a variable `INCLUDES`, together with `-I`. So, if we can somehow transfer the include directory of mpi installed in my user space to this variable, we are done. So, the question is reduced to how to transfer a user-defined value from `make`'s command line into Makefile's variable and override it if it has be defined, as is clearly asked in the question.

Fortunately `make` provides this command line option: `VAR=value`, so the option to answer my question is

```
make INCLUDES=-I/path/to/mpi/include/in/my/user/space
```